# Dropdownbutton hint not showing if the value is null

Tags: flutter, dart

What I want to do is when I first open the app, it should show the hint "Please select a car". The problem is, in order to hint to be seen, the value needs to be null. But when I do that, the car I choose is not showing in the menu.

Here's the full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late String _selectedCar;
  final List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> carsDropDownMenuItems = [
    DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Audi"), value: "Audi"),
    DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("BMW"), value: "BMW"),
    DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Honda"), value: "Honda"),
    DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Mercedes"), value: "Mercedes"),
    DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Skoda"), value: "Skoda"),
    DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Toyota"), value: "Toyota"),
  ];

  final Map<String, String> carLogos = {
    "Audi": "https://logowik.com/content/uploads/images/879_audi.jpg",
    "BMW":
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f4/BMW_logo_%28gray%29.svg/2048px-BMW_logo_%28gray%29.svg.png",
    "Honda":
        "https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/34/209/png-transparent-honda-logo.png",
    "Mercedes":
        "https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/519-5191333_mercedes-logo-png-logo-de-mercedes-benz-vector.png",
    "Skoda":
        "https://www.nicepng.com/png/detail/37-379850_skoda-logo-log-skoda-logo-transparent.png",
    "Toyota":
        "https://p.kindpng.com/picc/s/65-650458_toyota-land-cruiser-prado-car-toyota-camry-solara.png",
  };

  final Map<String, String> carDescriptions = {
    "Audi":
        "Audi AG is a German automotive manufacturer of luxury vehicles headquartered in Ingolstadt, Bavaria, Germany. As a subsidiary of its parent company, the Volkswagen Group, Audi produces vehicles in nine production facilities worldwide.",
    "BMW":
        "Bayerische Motoren Werke AG, commonly referred to as BMW, is a German multinational corporate manufacturer of luxury vehicles and motorcycles headquartered in Munich, Bavaria, Germany.",
    "Honda":
        "Honda Motor Company, Ltd. is a Japanese public multinational conglomerate manufacturer of automobiles, motorcycles, and power equipment, headquartered in Minato, Tokyo, Japan.",
    "Mercedes":
        "Mercedes-Benz, commonly referred to as Mercedes, is a German luxury automotive brand. Mercedes-Benz and subsidiary Mercedes-Benz AG – of Daimler AG – are headquartered in Stuttgart, Baden-Württemberg, Germany. Mercedes-Benz produces consumer luxury vehicles and commercial vehicles.",
    "Skoda":
        "Škoda Auto a.s. (Czech pronunciation: [ˈʃkoda] (About this soundlisten)), often shortened to Škoda, is a Czech automobile manufacturer founded in 1895 as Laurin & Klement and headquartered in Mladá Boleslav, Czech Republic.",
    "Toyota":
        "Toyota Motor Corporation is a Japanese multinational automotive manufacturer headquartered in Toyota City, Aichi, Japan. It was founded by Kiichiro Toyoda and incorporated on August 28, 1937. Toyota is one of the largest automobile manufacturers in the world, producing about 10 million vehicles per year.",
  };

  final TextStyle titleStyle = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 32,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
    color: Colors.blue,
  );

  final TextStyle subtextStyle = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 16,
  );

  Divider myDivider = Divider(
    thickness: 10,
    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 218, 210, 210),
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selectedCar = "Mercedes";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "cars title",
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("cars")),
        body: Center(
            child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 10),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    myDivider,
                    Text("Car Maker", style: titleStyle),
                    DropdownButton(
                      isExpanded: true,
                      hint: Text("Please select a car maker"),
                      items: carsDropDownMenuItems,
                      value: _selectedCar,
                      onChanged: ((value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedCar = value.toString();
                        });
                      }),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    myDivider,
                    Text("Logo", style: titleStyle),
                    Image.network(
                      carLogos[_selectedCar] ??
                          "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/No_image_available.svg/1024px-%20No_image_available.svg.png",
                      height: 230,
                    ),
                    Text("no image available"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    myDivider,
                    Text("Description", style: titleStyle),
                    Text(
                        carDescriptions[_selectedCar] ??
                            "No description available",
                        style: subtextStyle),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              myDivider,
            ],
          ),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I believe the problem is here when I do this:

```
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   _selectedCar = "Mercedes";
 }
```

I define _selecetedCar as anything from the carsDropDownMenuItems because I have to use
`late String _selectedCar;`  at first, otherwise it gives a LateInitializationError.

How can I make it so when I first open the app the menu bar says "Please select a car", and when I choose a car it shows in the menu bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `late String _selectedCar;` with `String? _selectedCar,` 
and remove   `_selectedCar = "Mercedes";` from initState();

---

read more about null safety, and late initialization,
**In your case**, you have to make your variable nullable. 
the nullable variable can has a null value, while late var cannot, and when you define a variable as late, you tell flutter SDK that this variable isn't nullable and it will be take a value during runtime and before used.